# tex4ebook: \bookmarksetup{startatroot} does not reset bookmark level

Tags: tex4ht, bookmarks, tex4ebook

I'm compiling a .tex document to .epub with tex4ebook and I would like the back matter of the book (additional chapters, glossary, index, references) to appear in the bookmarks at the top level (same as the front matter and each part of the body of the book). If I'm compiling to .pdf, `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` resets the bookmark level, but if I'm compiling to .epub, the back matter remains under the last "part". Any recommendations for how I can move the back matter to the top level of the bookmarks are appreciated.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeindex[intoc=true]

\begin{document}

\part{Mammalia}
\chapter{Monotremata}
platypus\index{platypus}

\backmatter
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}

\chapter{Afterword}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `\renewcommand\bookmarksetup[1]{\backmatter}` in the `.cfg` file? It will put next chapter to the top-level.

Comment: The Afterword section remained within the previous Part. The redefined command only moved one copy of the Index bookmark to the top level. There are duplicates of glossary, index, and references in the bookmarks which I remove in a .mk4 file in the original. The remaining bookmarks for these sections are not moved. Strangely when I created a minimal .mk4 to add to my question that only removed the Index bookmark, the redefinition worked and both the Afterword and Index were moved. It looks like there's an issue with how I'm removing the duplicates. I'll post a separate question about this.